# How to convert from Navit to PostGIS or shapefile?

Tags: convert, postgis-2.0

I have a Navit BIN file which I want to use in PostGIS or QGIS, so I need to import it to PostGIS or convert it to a shapefile.  I have found a lot of information on how to convert data TO the Navit format, but nothing on how to do the reverse.

Is this possible?  Is there an exporter?